# Rails - collection_check_boxes not triggering callbacks on join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Since the original question didn't hit the mark, here's a re-written version, which better describes the issue.

I have the following models:

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_item_options, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :options, through: :line_item_options
end

class LineItemOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :line_item
  has_many :charges, as: :chargeable, dependent: :destroy

  after_create :build_charges

  def build_charges
    surcharges.each do |surcharge|
     self.charges.create!(
       surcharge_id: surcharge.id,
       name: surcharge.name
     )
    end
  end
end

class Charge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chargeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

LineItemOption is the join model which joins an Option(not shown) to a LineItem.  In some cases the LineItemOption will also have a child Charge model.

In my LineItem form I have the following code:

```
= line_item.collection_check_boxes :option_ids, group.options, :id, :name_and_price do |option|
  .checkbox
    = option.check_box(class: "check")
    = option.label
```

When a LineItemOption is created using the `collection_check_boxes` form helper, the `after_create` callback fires as anticipated.  However when a LineItemOption is destroyed using this same form helper no callback is fired.  To test this I've used `has_many :charges, as: :chargeable, dependent: :destroy` as well as a before_destroy callback.  In both cases the callbacks work from the rails console, but not the collection_check_boxes form helper.

Looking at the server log I can see that the destroy method is being called on the LineItemOption which happily runs without also running the appropriate callback

```
LineItemOption Destroy (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "line_item_options" WHERE "line_item_options"."line_item_id" = $1 AND "line_item_options"."option_id" = $2  [["line_item_id", 12], ["option_id", 1]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orders/6
```

Im sitting here scratching my head trying to figure out whats going on, and how to address it.  Is this common behavior with the `collection_check_boxes` helper?

Comment: Are you sure rails is using `delete` instead of `destroy` (you can add a before_destroy callback on the associated model to check that)? show your controller action too

Comment: thanks @arieljoud, It turns out my original wording on this question was pretty poor, I've since re-written the question.

Comment: It looks like there's a bug or something in rails since a long time ago where the after_destroy callback is not triggered when you delete records from a has_many :through association https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27099 (and I guess the `dependant: :destroy` option depends on that callback). You'll have to implement some hacky solution (before assigning the new line_items, do `line_item.line_item_options.destroy_all` or `line_item.line_item_options.each(&:destroy)`)

Comment: Thank you @arielJuod, what a strange bug/feature.  Ok so here's what Im wondering, where do I put that code?  I tried a `before_save` as well as `after_validation` callback on the `LineItem` model, but it seems like the associated records are created before the model is created.  This results in the associated models being created and then destroyed by my method.

Comment: You didn't show your controller, but I suppose you do, at some point, something like `@line_item.update_attributes(line_item_params)` to update the line item. Before doing that, remove the line_item_options manually so rails doesn't do that wrong.

Comment: Hey that works out great! thank you @arialjuod, what I ended up doing was placing: `@line_item.line_item_options.destroy_all if @line_item.valid?` just before: `@line_item.update(line_item_params)`.  It does double validate the record, once here, and once on save, but your recommendation was the cleanest I could find.  If you want to add an answer to the question, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a bug or something in rails since a long time ago where the `after_destroy` callback is not triggered when you delete records from a `has_many :through` association https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27099 (and I guess the `dependant: :destroy` option depends on that callback).

You'll have to implement some hacky solution like, before assigning the new line_items, do something like `line_item.line_item_options.destroy_all` or `line_item.line_item_options.each(&:destroy)` to delete the records by hand triggering the propper callbacks and then updating the record so rails can create the new associations without the buggy destoy behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You must include:

```
has_many :line_item_options, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_item_options, :allow_destroy => true
```

You must add _destroy in your params:

```
def line_item_params
     params.require(:line_item).permit(line_item_options_attributes: [ .......,  :_destroy])

end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've re-written the question to hopefully make the issue a little clearer.